# error during signin in authentication_pages_spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, railstutorial.org

Fllowing the Michael hartl tutorial i'm getting the following error "undefined method pages" in authentication_pages_spec during sign in Chapter 8.

[image: first image]

[image]

authentication_pages_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe "AuthenticationPages", type: :request do

  subject { pages }

    describe "signin pages" do
        before { visit signin_path }

        it { should have_selector('h1', text: 'Sign in')}
        it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign in')}
    end

    describe "signin" do
        before { visit signin_path }

        describe "with invalid information" do
            before { click_button "Sign in" }

            it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign in')}
            it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-error', text: 'Invalid')}

      describe "after visiting another page" do
          before { click_link "Home" }
          it { should_not have_selector('div.alert.alert-error') }
      end
        end

        describe "with valid information" do
            let(:user) {FactoryGirl.create(:user)}
            before do
                fill_in "Email", with: user.email
                fill_in "Password", with: user.password
                click_button "Sign in"
            end

            it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
            it { should have_link('Profile', href: user_path(user))}
            it { should have_link('Sign out', href: signout_path)}
            it { should_not have_link('Sign in', href: signin_path)}
        end
    end
end
```

new.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, "Sign in") %>
<h1>Sign in</h1>

<div class = "row">
    <div class = "col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <%= form_for(:session, url: sessions_path) do |f| %>

            <%= f.label :email %>
            <%= f.text_field :email %>

            <%= f.label :password %>
            <%= f.password_field :password %>

            <%= f.submit "Sign in", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>

            <p> New user? <%= link_to "Sign up now", signup_path %></p>

        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :users
  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]

  root to: 'static_pages#home'
  get '/signup', to: 'users#new'
  get '/signin', to: 'sessions#new'
  get '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', via: :delete
  get '/help', to: 'static_pages#help'
  get '/about', to: 'static_pages#about'
  resources :users
end
```

Session_controller.rb

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

    def new
    end

    def create
        user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email])
        if user && user.authennticate(params[:session][:password])
            #Sign the user in a redirect to the user's show page.
        else
            #Create an error message and re-render the signin form
            flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    def destroy
    end

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using an old version of the tutorial (the [current version](https://www.railstutorial.org/book) uses MiniTest instead of RSpec), so you should probably consider switching over.

As for your errors, you would seem to have two spelling mistakes:

- Change `pages` to `page` (singular), as that is the object that Capybara makes assertions against
- Change `user.authennticate` to `user.authenticate`

For future questions, please copy and paste any error output in text format and refrain from posting screenshots.